# Assembly language label confusion

Tags: c++, assembly

I have compiled the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function declaration
int max(int num1, int num2);

int main ()
{
   // local variable declaration:
   int a = 100;
   int b = 200;
   int ret;

   // calling a function to get max value.
   ret = max(a, b);

   cout << "Max value is : " << ret << endl;

   return 0;
}

// function returning the max between two numbers
int max(int num1, int num2) 
{
   // local variable declaration
   int result;

   if (num1 > num2)
      result = num1;
   else
      result = num2;

   return result; 
}
```

I has generated the assembly language below:

```
.file   "CallFunction.cpp"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "Max value is : \0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
.LFB969:
    subq    $40
    leaq    .LC0(%rip, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main), %rdx
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rcx
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movl    $200, %edx
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .globl  _Z3maxii
    .def    _Z3maxii;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _Z3maxii
_Z3maxii:
.LFB970:
    .seh_endprologue
    cmpl    %edx, %ecx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    cmovge  %ecx, %eax
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    _GLOBAL__sub_I_main;    .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB980:
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rcx
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .ctors,"w"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .text
    .def    _GLOBAL__sub_D_main;    .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _GLOBAL__sub_D_main
_GLOBAL__sub_D_main:
.LFB981:
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rcx
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .dtors,"w"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_D_main
.lcomm _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1"
    .def    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSolsEi;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout, "dr"
    .globl  .refptr._ZSt4cout
    .linkonce   discard
.refptr._ZSt4cout:
    .quad   _ZSt4cout
```

I was expecting two labels (one for each method), however there appear to be six.  Why are there six? Also, how does the naming convention work i.e. what does ".LFB969" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The optimiser has converted your `main` to

```
int main ()
{
   cout << "Max value is : " << 200 << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Which it is allowed to do, since it has exactly the same effect.

Your two functions are labelled `_Z3maxii` and `main`. The other labels are purely for the compiler's benefit - looks like it sticks one at the beginning and end of each function.

The .Lxxxx labels are mechanically generated (not based on any text in your program); there's no particular significance to the names.